# android: Galaxy Note 2 : for which pixel layout images/icon should be prepared?

Tags: android, android-layout, galaxy

I am developing an app which must support Samsung Galaxy Note - 2.
Now [note-2's](http://www.samsung.com/in/galaxynote2/spec.html?type=find) pixel resolution is 1,280 x 720. Reference [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density).
While developing an app, I found that it was picking images from `res/drawable-hdpi`. 
So for what resolution layout I should prepare the images ? Or do need to make separate resource folder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resources are picked based on DPI a quick reference for what DPI each device uses can be found here:

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/list-of-android-devices-with-pixel-density-buckets/

For image scaling, the images should roughly be sized like so:

if an image is to use 100 **dp** then the actual images sizes will be:

- ldpi:  75px
- mdpi:  100px
- hdpi:  150px
- xhdpi: 200px

if you want to use 100 **px** on your NOTE 2 then the image sizes will be

- ldpi: 50px
- mdpi:  66.67px
- hdpi:  100px
- xhdpi: 133.33px

you can use the following site do do quick calculations:

http://labs.skinkers.com/content/android_dp_px_calculator/

Answer (score 2):

Prepare images for hdpi resolution -- 480x800 hdpi.

Answer (score 2):

Galaxy Note 2 is normal size, xhdpi density and long. You can prepare layout or drawable for xhdpi. For details, please check this post [Galaxy Note 2 screen specifications](http://situee.blogspot.com/2013/01/galaxy-note-2-screen-specifications.html). If you don't have xhdpi resource, android will try to find resource in hdpi.

Comment: I just tested this on my note 2 and it pulls from values-hdpi not values-xhdpi.

Answer (score 1):

The Galaxy Note uses hdpi which is a pixel density of 240dpi

[Android Device Resolutions](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/list-of-android-devices-with-pixel-density-buckets/)

Comment: hdpi does not specific a resolution, it specifies a pixel density bucket of 240dpi. That is all.